# How to determine if the response in NSURLCache has expired?

Tags: ios, nsurlcache

Is there a good way to determine if the response in NSURLCache has expired? When I call -cachedResponseForRequest: method, it returns non-nil value even for expired requests, but Cocoa connects to the server and then updates NSURLCache.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the HTTP headers being returned in the response. NSURLCache will check the headers to decide if it can use the thing returned from the cache.

Comment: Ok, I'm sure our server returns such headers. Let me clarify things. What I exactly mean is how to determine if my SECOND request, which occurs after some arbitrary time after the FIRST request, uses cached response or receives data via a network?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://blackpixel.com/blog/2012/05/caching-and-nsurlconnection.html

Comment: Thanks for answers. I'll take a look at `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` protocol

Comment: @SergeyDunets my pleasure, remember to mark my answer as correct, if it's answered your question ;)